# Excel - Find and replace using a combined (value and formatting) condition

Tags: excel, replace, format, find

I want to empty and set cell formatting to General for all cells in a sheet which:

- contain "MyText" and
- are formatted as percentage

I am using the Find&Replace dialog (CTRL+H), but:

- if I leave the "Replace With" box empty, then only the formatting is replaced; the "MyText" is still there;
- if I write "SomeText" into the "Replace with" box, the text replacement is also performed, together with the format replace

It looks like I can't get both replacements (empty text and changed formatting) in one go.

Is there any wildcard for "nothing" that I can use in the "Replace with:" field? Or any other easy solution to this?

**Update:**
I tried recording a macro.
This does text *and* format replacement:

```
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "General"
Cells.Replace What:="MyText", Replacement:="nothing", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, _
    ReplaceFormat:=True
```

but if I remove the Replacement text, it only does the formatting replacement (which makes sense up to a point, but this is not what I want to achieve)

```
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "General"
Cells.Replace What:="MyText", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, _
    ReplaceFormat:=True
```

Comment: Do the cells contain *text* or *formulas* returning text ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent :No formulas, just text; if it had formulas, the text substitution would not work at all; but it works if I supply that argument; I only need to know how I can supply the `blank` argument; `""` is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a simple loop may be easier:

```
Sub FixingData()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        With r
            If .Value = "MyText" Then
                If .NumberFormat = "0.00%" Then
                    .ClearContents
                    .NumberFormat = "General"
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version may be a little faster:

```
Sub FixingDataFast()
    Dim r As Range, rUnion As Range
    Dim calcM

    Set rUnion = Nothing
    calcM = Application.Calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If r.Value = "MyText" Then
            If r.NumberFormat = "0.00%" Then
                If rUnion Is Nothing Then
                    Set rUnion = r
                Else
                    Set rUnion = Union(rUnion, r)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If rUnion Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rUnion.ClearContents
        rUnion.NumberFormat = "General"
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = calcM
End Sub
```

Comment: If I run your code, I get an error at the first `If`whe it ecounters the first cell which satisifes the condition. If I change the `.Value` into `Formula` it runs fine

Comment: Also, it runs quite slow: on my test file, and it took 10 seconds using the loop; however, doing 2 Find&Replaces via macro (once for format, once for text) takes less than 1 second.

Comment: @horace_vr  I was trying to change only cells that had **both** the matching text and the matching format, not all cells with *%* formatting; perhaps I did not understand want you wanted..........I don't understand why `.Value` fails and `.Formula` works ??

Comment: @horace_vr  I still do not know why `.Value` fails.

Comment: your loop's logic is fine - I need both conditions; I was just comparing the times needed to run; the macro which makes 2 Find&Replaces performs some unwanted replacements as well. The `.value` thing puzzles me as well...

Comment: @horace_vr  We can improve the speed by restricting the macro to  process only specific columns or specific rows.

Comment: @horace_vr  We can also improve speed by doing only one `.ClearContents`

Comment: technically, we can also do `.ClearFormats`. What do you have in mind ?

Comment: @horace_vr I avoided .`ClearFormats`, because that would also clear colors.  I will try to update my code to improve speed..........check back later......

Comment: @horace_vr  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124377/discussion-between-horace-vr-and-garys-student).